# Validating the model outside of the controller in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wasn't quite sure whether I should do it this way or create a validation service and inject it, but this works:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> NewUser(NewUsertVm viewModel)
{
    if (UserValidator.NewUserIsValid(viewModel, ModelState) == false)
    {
        return View(nameof(NewUser), viewModel);
    }

// Code omitted for brevity   
}
```

UserValidatorClass

```
public static bool NewUserIsValid(NewUserVm viewModel, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.RefOne) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.RefTwo) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.RefThree))
    {
        var validationMessage =
            "At least one of either the first, second or third ref numbers must be entered to add a new user. Please enter one of these numbers and try again.";
        modelState.AddModelError(nameof(viewModel.RefOne), validationMessage);
    }

    var regEx = new Regex("(^\\d{10}$)");

    if (viewModel.RefOne != null)
    {
        if (!regEx.IsMatch(viewModel.RefOne))
        {
            var validationMessage =
                "Ref One must be 10 digits and contain only numbers.";
                modelState.AddModelError(nameof(viewModel.RefOne), validationMessage);
        }
    }

    return modelState.IsValid;
}
```

The idea behind the validator is that it needs to ensure at least one of the three properties are not null (RefOne, RefTwo & Ref Three. Property names have been changed for post). If RefOne is used, it needs to match the RegEx pattern.

This appears to work as intended but is there a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Why `IValidatableObject` does not suit for your needs?

Comment: I would suggest injecting it because you may end up having validation services that have dependencies. I tend to prefer doing this work in an action filter